# What models and brands can I find for logic fuses?

Tags: lithium-ion, fuses, batteries, laptop

I'm trying to find logic fuses like [the ones found here.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/189316/what-could-be-this-component-and-what-is-its-work-is-it-a-fuse-or-may-be-a-prot/189630#)

As I'm new user, I couldn't comment there, so I created this new question.

That fuse, in my case, is on a Clevo P170EM battery. This battery model is P150HMBAT-8 (6-87-X710S-4273).

I would also like to ask if these types of fuses can be replaced at home with a simple ersa i-Con Pico soldering station.

Comment: `I couldn't comment there` ... that is a very good thing ... it is no place for your question ... anyway, what results do you think you would get by asking your question in the comments of an old post? ... please, do not ever hijack any post in that way

Comment: the post that you linked was closed as a duplicate ... have a look at the original post ..... refer to the datasheet for solderability information

Comment: @jsotola I didn't want to spam the forum with a question that was already here. Many places in the internet, such as forums, always require you to use search and use the existent threads when the subject is the same. Old posts, when bumped are no longer "old". Can't understand the problem with old posts.
Also, if I didn't know the model/reference of the fuse, how was I supposed to "look to the datasheet?" Weird that suggestion, no? Anyways, I already found what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: thank you for trying to be considerate ... this site is not a forum, it is a question/answer site ... you post a question and someone, hopefully, will answer it ... comments are used to request clarification ... clarification should usually be edited into the question ... if you have an answer to your question, then you can post the answer and accept it as solved

Answer (score 2):

This is where some more info can be found about the component I was looking for.

Here is the datasheet:

[image: datasheet]

(Click image for larger version)

<sub>Source of original PDF version of datasheet image: [Ogatama](http://www.ogatama.com/fc-l.pdf)</sub>

In my case, I removed the fuse, and looked underneath to be able to see the reference. It said SEFUSE D6X238. Happens that the '238' part is apparently a lot number (or some date code as some brand support person told me by email).

So, what we need to search is only by "SEFUSE D6X".

I found some parts on a well know sales site. I can provide links to the item in that site, maybe by PM or so, because I think you cannot easily find them by regular search.